# Database first - Add controller properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Here's the thing: I built an app from an existing database. Later some changes were made to the db so I needed to add those fields to my controllers.
I added a few properties to my Users class like so:

```
public string GHProducts { get; set; }
```

and then on the View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.GHProducts)
```

I also have some other properties not showing on the form, which I set from the controller in the create new user action. But neither of them is being set when users get created, all registries have NULL values for these manually added properties. So I'm obviously missing something and can't figure out how to bind everything together. I tried the "replace from server" option, but it didn't solve anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to [update your edmx file with the database changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716697.aspx).